# How to change datatype of a column containing data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a table in my SQL Server DB.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]([col3] [varchar](50) NULL, [col4] [varchar](50) NULL, [col5] [char](1) NULL)
```

Following is the data in the table:

```
col3    col4    col5
sad     asdf    c
df      sdfg    b
```

Now I want to change the datatype of 'col5' to INT. Tried this:

```
alter table [dbo].[TABLE2] alter column [col5] int null;
```

Encountered this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'c' to data type int.
The statement has been terminated.
```

After changing the datatype to INT - I want to change 'c' to 100 and 'b' to 101.

How can I change the datatype and the data? Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must increase your `col5`:

```
alter table [dbo].[TABLE2] alter column [col5] varchar(10) null;
```

Then `UPDATE` your data to something such as numbers. Maybe:

```
UPDATE Table set col5 = '100' where col5='c'
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alter column - wouldn't work for type conversions from varchar to int/long/etc.,

- You will have to create a new int column
- Then copy all the existing data from col5 to new int column
- and then delete the col5 column from TABLE2

There could be smarter ways. However, this serves the purpose i guess.